# What is Ogre::String?

Tags: c++, ogre

I was working with the OGRE .NET bindings (MOGRE) for quite a long time. To improve my (not that good) C++ skills, I am switching from C# to C++.

After implementing a basic OGRE application, I was curious why Ogre has it's own String class **Ogre::String?**
Why is it used and not **std:string**?

Can/shall I mix these String types and what shall I use in my OGRE application for non-OGRE tasks/methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Frameworks in C++ tend to use their own string implementation to solve Unicode and localization issues. Unicode support in C++ is generally not that good even in C++11. std::string can't store Unicode characters.

If you want to take advantage of unicode and probably localization you may want to use their string.

Comment: Thank you for that useful information. In this case, I will use the OGRE string implementation in my project.

Comment: What exactly makes you say that the C++11 string implementation isn't good for unicode? `std::string` will store almost any unicode character, especially with the advent of `u` `u8` and `U`. On windows you might have to use `std::wstring` though.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode the reasons are summerized here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103925/how-well-is-unicode-supported-in-c11

Comment: I'm not referring to the management of unicode strings, I was replying to your comment "std::string can't store Unicode characters." which it most certainly can; some compilers won't let it though.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode UTF8 doesn't mean each code point is 1 byte actually it can be 8 16 or even 24, char is supposed to represent 1 byte in the C and C++ standard even if the underlying implementation use a different size.

Comment: std::string does not store Unicode characters. It stores 8-bit codepoints. Those codepoints might happen to be valid UTF-8, but that's neither here nor there. The Standard library has basically zero support for Unicode.

Comment: Yes it does, just because it doesn't treat them as so doesn't mean that it doesn't. If you use the ICU library, you have to read all unicode strings into an `std::string` before decoding them with the library. AGAIN I wasn't referring to managing the strings in a standard `std::string`

Comment: @concept3d unicode codepoints can only be 1-4bytes, I think you mean bits.

Comment: `char[4] == float` just represented differently. Just like `char[2] == char16_t`. Final representation means nothing when all we are storing is bytes, and with an `std::string`, we are.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode yes, I meant bits, what I wanted to say was summarized in DeadMG comment. We don't really care about individual code points, we care about character and that's why string is not adequate.